# How do I dynamically reload snippets in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

When I create a plugin, and change the `.py` file, it automatically reloads and the changes take effect in Sublime Text 3 immediately. When I create a `.sublime-snippet` file it seems to be updated only after restarting Sublime.

UPD: this interesting behavior on symbolic link. A make in Packages folder symbolic link to git repo, where exist .py and snipets. When change .py plugin automatically reload, snepets doesn't. In true folder in Packages everything work fine!

Comment: mine update as soon as I save a new version, on both Sublime 2 and 3. Can you [edit] your question and describe in more detail what exactly you are doing, and what effects you are seeing?

Comment: Same issue happens with me. I symlink my packages to Dropbox, so they're the same on multiple machines, and saving a snippet doesn't cause it to reload.

Comment: Yes, I try make the same thing apply rsync to my plugin path.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the symlink issue, you could always do a `mount --bind <src> <dest>`. This mounts the (Dropbox, whatever...) folder like a volume with a true path. When you look at it, a symlink is just a file, which would explain the update not occurring.

The alternative of creating a hard link only works for files, not folders, by the way.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

**[My Snippets](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/My%20Snippets)** has a `livesync` feature @ [MySnippets.sublime-settings](https://github.com/erikgassler/My-Snippets/blob/master/MySnippets.sublime-settings#L20).  You can specify the snippet updating frequency in milliseconds.